# How to return the actual object from a QListWidget in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a list of objects/class instances and a QListWidget.

```
my_objects = [obj1, obj2, obj3]
self.all_objects = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
```

The ListWidget is filled with the names of my_objects.

```
for i in my_objects:
self.all_objects.addItem(i.name)
```

Once an item in the ListWidget is selected I run a function called listwidgetclicked.

```
self.all_objects.itemClicked.connect(self.listwidgetclicked)
```

In this function I would like to access various attributes of the instances, but the itemClicked method seems to return a QListWidgetItem object instead of the original obj1 or obj2 or obj3, which means I am unable to access the attributes of said objects.

I assume one fault could be that in the for loop, I am adding i.name instead of i itself, however adding just i results in a type error, because addItem method takes (self, str) as parameters, not an object.

Once an item in the list is selected, I would like it to return the actual objects, so that I can later access their attributes in a function. How can this be achieved?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All item models in Qt use ["roles"](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#item-roles).

On standard models, those roles define the appearance of each model *index*, using the default [ItemDataRole](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum)s:

- `DisplayRole` is used to show the (possible) text displayed
- `DecorationRole` is used for the "decoration" (aka: the icon)
- etc.

Qt allows to define custom roles for underlying data which might be used to store any kind of information for each model index.

To set *any* kind of data for each index, you can use the base [`setData(index, value, role)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#setData) method. This means that you can create a custom *role* for your model and set the data for each index using the object you need a reference for.

```
CustomObjectRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # ...
        my_objects = [obj1, obj2, obj3]
        self.all_objects = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)

        for i in my_objects:
            item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(i.name)
            self.all_objects.addItem(item)
            item.setData(CustomObjectRole, i)
```

Then, to access that object, you only need to access the item and then use [`item.data(role)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidgetitem.html#data) or [`self.item(itemRow)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#item).`data(role)`. Alternatively, you can use the model's [`index.(row, column)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#index) and use `index.data(role)` from there.

```
def listwidgetclicked(self, item):
    obj = item.data(CustomObjectRole)
    # do something...
```

Note that, to ensure drag'n'drop functionalities, the custom role[s] data *must* be "pickle"-able (it *has* to be able to convert to/from bytestream data in some way).